# How to pass 2 values to AJAX function to be parsed as JSON?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an AJAX function

```
function updatelink(linktochange){


  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "profile/...../rder.php",
  data: {id:linktochange, value:val},
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function(result) {
     alert ("Update successful!!")

  }
  });
}
```

and my jQuery

```
 <input value="'+lnk+'" id="'+usId+'<seperator>'+orId+'<seperator>'+poId+'"  class="linkinput" onBlur="updatelink(this.id)">\
```

I am able to send the ID using this.id, but how to send both ID and Value to the ajax to be parsed?

To be more specific I need something like this `onBlur="updatelink(this.id && this.value)`.

I don't even know what to search on the web to find an answer for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <input value="'+lnk+'" id="'+usId+'<seperator>'+orId+'<seperator>'+poId+'"  class="linkinput" onBlur="updatelink(this.id,this.value)">

    function updatelink(linktochange,val){


      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "profile/...../rder.php",
      data: {id:linktochange, value:val},
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
         alert ("Update successful!!")

      }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar, it works i was trying && and .... but didn't think about ,  loool that's how minds go complicated